# Why can't I write to an @ObservedObject?

Tags: swiftui

I have a struct called Activity which has an id (`UUID`), name (`String`), description (`String`) and timesCompleted (`Int`).

I also have a class called Activities that contains an array of Activity structs called activityList. Activities is marked with `ObservableObject`.

I have activities declared as a `@StateObject` in my ContentView and I pass it to my ActivityDetailView where it is declared as an `@ObservedObject`.

However I can only partially write to `activities.activityList` in the child view. I can append, but I can't overwrite, update or remove an element from the array. No error is thrown but the view immediately crashes and the app returns to the main `ContentView`.

How do you update/write to an `@ObservedObject`? As you can see from the comments in my `updateTimesCompleted()` function I've tried all kinds of things to update/overwrite an existing element. All crash silently and return to `ContentView`. Append does not fail, but isn't the behavior I want, I want to update/overwrite an array element, not append a new copy.

Activity Struct:

```
struct Activity : Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var timesCompleted: Int
}
```

Activities Class:

```
class Activities: ObservableObject {
    @Published var activityList = [Activity]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(activityList) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "activityList")
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        if let savedList = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "activityList") {
            if let decodedList = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Activity].self, from: savedList) {
                activityList = decodedList
                return
            }
        }
        activityList = []
    }
    
    init(activityList: [Activity]) {
        self.activityList = activityList
    }
    
    subscript(index: Int) -> Activity {
        get {
            assert(index < activityList.count, "Index out of range")
            return activityList[index]
        }
        
        set {
            assert(index < activityList.count, "Index out of range")
            activityList[index] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var activities = Activities()
    @State private var showingAddActivity = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(activities.activityList) { activity in
                    NavigationLink {
                        ActivityDetailView(activity: activity, activities: activities)
                    } label: {
                        Text(activity.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Habits")
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    showingAddActivity = true
                    let _ = print("add activity")
                }
            label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddActivity) {
            AddActivityView(activities: activities)
        }
    }
}
```

ActivityDetailView:

```
struct ActivityDetailView: View {
    @State private var timesCompleted = 0
    let activity: Activity
    
    @ObservedObject var activities: Activities
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Text("Activity: \(activity.name)")
                Text("Description: \(activity.description)")
                
                Stepper {
                    Text("Times Completed: \(timesCompleted)")
                } onIncrement: {
                    timesCompleted += 1
                    updateTimesCompleted()
                } onDecrement: {
                    if timesCompleted > 0 {
                        timesCompleted -= 1
                        updateTimesCompleted()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Activity Details")
        }
    }
    
    func updateTimesCompleted() {
        let newActivity = Activity(name: activity.name, description: activity.description, timesCompleted: timesCompleted)

        let _ = print("count: \(activities.activityList.count)")
        
        let index = activities.activityList.firstIndex(of: activity)
        let _ = print(index ?? -666)
        if let index = index {
            activities.activityList[index] = Activity(name: activity.name, description: activity.description, timesCompleted: timesCompleted)
            
            //activities.activityList.swapAt(index, activities.activityList.count - 1)
            //activities.activityList[index].incrementTimesCompleted()
            //activities.activityList.append(newActivity)
            //activities.activityList.remove(at: index)
            //activities.activityList.removeAll()
            //activities.activityList.append(newActivity)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into `AppStorage` and [Check out Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022)

Comment: I don't think AppStorage is necessary to solve this issue. It was a binding problem.

Comment: that is why I liked the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this approach, where the `activity` is passed to the `ActivityDetailView`
as a binding.

In addition, `@ObservedObject var activities: Activities` is used directly in `AddActivityView` to add an `Activity` to the list.

```
struct Activity : Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID() // <-- here
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var timesCompleted: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { // <-- here
        case name,description,timesCompleted
    }
}

class Activities: ObservableObject {
    @Published var activityList = [Activity]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(activityList) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "activityList")
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        if let savedList = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "activityList") {
            if let decodedList = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Activity].self, from: savedList) {
                activityList = decodedList
                return
            }
        }
        activityList = []
    }
    
    init(activityList: [Activity]) {
        self.activityList = activityList
    }
    
    subscript(index: Int) -> Activity {
        get {
            assert(index < activityList.count, "Index out of range")
            return activityList[index]
        }
        set {
            assert(index < activityList.count, "Index out of range")
            activityList[index] = newValue
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var activities = Activities()
    @State private var showingAddActivity = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach($activities.activityList) { $activity in   // <-- here
                    NavigationLink {
                        ActivityDetailView(activity: $activity) // <-- here
                    } label: {
                        Text(activity.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Habits")
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    showingAddActivity = true
                }
            label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddActivity) {
            AddActivityView(activities: activities)
        }
        .onAppear {
            // for testing
            if activities.activityList.isEmpty {
                activities.activityList.append(Activity(name: "activity-1", description: "activity-1", timesCompleted: 1))
                activities.activityList.append(Activity(name: "activity-2", description: "activity-2", timesCompleted: 2))
                activities.activityList.append(Activity(name: "activity-3", description: "activity-3", timesCompleted: 3))
            }
        }
    }
    
}

// -- here for testing
struct AddActivityView: View {
    @ObservedObject var activities: Activities
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("AddActivityView")
        Button("add activity") {
            activities.activityList.append(Activity(name: "workingDog", description: "workingDog", timesCompleted: 5))
        }
    }
}

struct ActivityDetailView: View {
    @Binding var activity: Activity  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("Activity: \(activity.name)")
            Text("Description: \(activity.description)")
            
            Stepper {
                Text("Times Completed: \(activity.timesCompleted)")
            } onIncrement: {
                activity.timesCompleted += 1  // <-- here
            } onDecrement: {
                if activity.timesCompleted > 0 {
                    activity.timesCompleted -= 1  // <-- here
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The binding was what was needed. Specifically in the ForEach and NavigationLink in ContentView. Didn't need the CodingKeys enum though.

Comment: When you use `let id = UUID()`, (note the let), you don't need the CodingKeys. The `id` will not be decoded from the json, however you will get a warning from the compiler telling you this. To remove that warning, that some people find alarming, you use the `CodingKeys` without the `id`, and all is good then.
 Alternatively you can use a `var id = UUID()` as you do, but IMHO, `id` should be a `let`.